# displaying each item from a multidimensional array in a different div javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a multidimensional array formed from 9 arrays with 9 elements each, how can I loop through them and display each array item in a different div? Each div should have an array item.

This is my code so far.
[link to my method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aECb.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use `.forEach` to loop in JS arrays. There are many ways. Try  reading about them.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We expect people to do research, give it a go... and if they're still struggling, show us their code in a [mcve]. Your "question" show no evidence of any of this. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: I have a list with all the divs. Starting with a for loop with the length of the div list I have a 'i' index. For the multidimensional array I have a 'j' index in a for loop based on the length of the multidim array. I tried tot do this: divList[i].innerHTML = multiArray[i][j]. The problem is that it loops the multi array but it will only display the last element of the small arrays.

Comment: Basically, it looks like this: for (var i = 0; x < divList.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++) {
                    divList[i].innerText = multiArray[i][j];
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get all elements in multidimensional array.

 Using simple `.lenght` function and `for` loops.

```
 let myArray = [{"child": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]}, 
                   {"child": ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"]}];

    for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

       let childArray = myArray[i].child;

       for(let j = 0; j < childArray.length; j++){

      console.log(childArray[j]);

       }

    }
```

Comment: where I am write console.log add your code to add text to div